# Get text inside the pair of outside brackets

Tags: c#, string

I need to get the text from the outside pair of brackets
So from the text like this with unknown number of inside blocks:

> Block1{{text1}{text2} ... {text n}}

get the result:

> {text1}

and

> {text2} ....{text n}

Is there an easy way how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I found a lot of topics where they use regex to get text from the brackets. But I would like to know if there is a similar way to do it like that but with the result i described here.

Comment: So why don't you share the code you've written so far?

Comment: Something like this? https://ideone.com/EU9Bh1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.

```
    String pattern = @"(Block[0-9]+){({[^}]+})*}";
    String text = @"Block1{{text1}{text2}{text3}{text4}{text5}{text6}}Block2{{text1}{text2}{text3}}";
    foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("---------");
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Match: `" + match.ToString() + "`");

        foreach(Group grp in match.Groups) 
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("    Group: `" + grp.Value + "`");
            foreach(Capture cpt in grp.Captures)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("        Capture: `" + cpt.Value + "`");
            }
        }
    }
```

Breaking down the regular expression pattern:

Capture the literal `Block` and zero or more numerical digits:

```
(Block[0-9]+)
```

Process a literal `{`:

```
{
```

Capture zero or more repetitions of a literal `{`, one or more of anything but `}`, and then a literal `}`:

```
({[^}]+})*
```

Process a literal `}`:

```
}
```

Here's a [.NET fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uYm51k)

**edit 2:** Based on conversation in the comments, the original question was intended to be broader. I think the following answer works for the specific case originally presented, but the answer above is generic.

You can use regular expressions.

```
    String pattern = @"{({[^}]+})({[^}]+})}";

    Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("---------");
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Match: `" + match.ToString() + "`");

    if (match.Groups.Count == 3)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("    Group 1: ``" + match.Groups[1].Value);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("    Group 2: ``" + match.Groups[2].Value);
    }
```

To break down this expression:

Match one opening curly braces:

```
{
```

Make a group out of one opening curly brace, one or more characters that are **not** a closing curly brace, and one closing curly brace.

```
({[^}]+})
```

Make a group out of one opening curly brace, one or more characters that are **not** a closing curly brace, and one closing curly brace.

```
({[^}]+})
```

Match one closing curly brace:

```
}
```

**edit:** I had made a mistake that I have corrected with the first regular expression; it yielded `text1` rather than `{text1}` and similarly for `text2`.

Comment: This is almost that, but it works only on this example, if I have the string with three inside blocks like this:
Block1{{text1}{text2}{text3}}

Then it does not work..:(

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to be more specific? Should it work on any number of inside blocks or just two or three?

Comment: On any number of blocks... that is the problem

Comment: What are the rules about what's allowed in a text block?

Comment: And is the whole thing inside of some other string, or is it in isolation?

Comment: The text but with no more brackets inside. 
It would be like this: 
{ {text1}{text2}{}..{text_n} }

Comment: Okay. If you don't mind, could you edit your question to reflect that?

Comment: Also, could this be like `Block1{{text1a}{text1b}}Block2{{text2a}{text2b}}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155954/discussion-between-jan-hakl-and-don-01001100).

Answer (score -3):

Try ***indexing*** **methods**. (Ex: Block1[0], Block1[1])

```
Block1[0]
```

Comment: The original question was asking about parsing a string literal.